# Hide custom Properties in editor pane but allow them to export.

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a custom web part that has custom properties. To Edit the properties I have a custom  EditorPart.

I need these properties to be able to be exported with the webpart. To do so I have to set the WebBrowsable attribute to true which makes the custom properties show up twice in the editor pane once with my editor part and my custom validation and once automatically.

Is there a way to get the properties to export with out setting WebBrowsable to true?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try setting the ExportMode property of your WebPart

There is a good explanation on MSDN here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpart.exportmode.aspx

Comment: I have set the ExportMode to ALL and only properties with WebBrowsable  to True.  I don't want to set WebBrowsable to True.